# Concatenating 2 Linked Lists - Java

Tags: java

I am having some trouble with NullPointExceptions when attempting to concatenate two linked lists in JAVA.

The code for main to test it is:

```
d1 = new MyDeque ();
d2 = new MyDeque ();
d2.pushLeft (11);
d1.concat (d2);
```

While the code for the concat function is:

```
public void concat (MyDeque that) {

    if (!that.isEmpty())
    {
        this.last.next = that.first;
        this.N += that.N;

        that.first = null;
        that.last = null;
        that.N = 0;
    }
}
```

The portion that I don't understand is that it flags NullPointerException.  "d2" or that isn't empty, and "d1" is, which sort of makes me understand that there would be a null value, "d1", pointing to the first value in "d2", aka 11, with this.last.next = that.first.  Should I make another statement that handles this differently if "d1" is empty as well?

Comment: What will happen if the first list is empty :)

Comment: I'm confused.  I'd presume that a linked list would concatenate by adding the other list to the end of itself, updating its size count, and moving its tail pointer to the same place that the others' tail pointer currently points to.  You're doing two of those three; why would you be getting a NPE?  **Where** are you getting a NPE?

Comment: @nmore this.last = that.first ?

Comment: Right so you need to check for this special case first. Otherwise this.last is null and this.last.next gives a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have your entire node class, I see 2 possible places for you to have a NullPointerException.

(1)

```
if (!that.isEmpty())
```

You should verify `(that != null)`.  Your code will throw a NullPointerException if `that` is null.

(2)

```
this.last.next = that.first;
```

Your code will throw a NullPointerException if `this.last` is null.  Make sure it isn't, or check beforehand.

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking.  If this.last is a null value, you would you instead just say this.last = that.first?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are checking that the next node is not empty

`while (list.next != null)`

Is the standard approach, it may be slightly different if you are using a custom end token